# Extract information from a website

Tags: html, vba, excel

Good Morning,

I have previously written macros to extract information from a website using information from an excel sheet. I used the Get command with the URL, to get the specific information I was searching for, it was as simple as putting the ID at the end of the URL, easy enough. This one is not as easy. I can not put the ID at the end of the URL, which is the extent of my VBA knowledge, I have been unsuccessful so far. The website is https://www.nctracks.nc.gov/publicPortal/provider/PractitionerSearch.action, how would I go about submitting an NPI from excel to the website? I know how to sift through the HTML to get the information, just not how to navigate there. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically use the developer tools in IE (f12) and find the element in question with ctrl + B    you'd need to tweak the value for your providerNPI, but you can use something like this:

```
Private IE As Object
Private ieDoc As Object
Const Readystate_Complete As Long = 4

Sub GetData()
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://www.nctracks.nc.gov/publicPortal/provider/PractitionerSearch.action"
    ieBusyLoop
    Set ieDoc = IE.document
    ieDoc.getElementbyID("providerNPI").Value = "1234567890"
    IeClickID ("search")
    Set ieDoc = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub IeClickID(ByVal ElId$)
    ieDoc.getElementbyID(ElId).Click
    OneSecDelay
    Call ieBusyLoop
End Sub
Private Sub OneSecDelay()
        waitTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
        Do Until Now >= waitTime: DoEvents: Loop
End Sub
Private Sub ieBusyLoop()
    Do While IE.busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until IE.readystate = Readystate_Complete: DoEvents: Loop
End Sub
```